# Guardar checkbox en mongodb con react hooks

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

Intento guardar con `React` hooks un formulario el cual contiene `checkboxs` que se encuentran por defecto seleccionados, pero a menos que los vuelva a deseleccionar y seleccionar no me permite guardarlos en `Mongodb`, o de lo contrario genera un error `Cast to Boolean failed for value "" at path`, o sea que es necesario hacer todo el proceso de deseleccionar y volver a seleccionar para que tome el valor, y la idea es que ya que se encuentra seleccionado no sea necesario volverlos a escoger, es la primera vez que tragabo en un proyecto con `checkbox` por lo que desconozco el proceso

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ingresaProducto } from "../actions/platoActions";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CreaAlmuerzoScreen(props) {
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("");
  const [Ensalada, habilitaEnsalada] = useState("");
  const [Principio, habilitaPrincipio] = useState("");
  const [Bebida, habilitaBebida] = useState("");

  const redirigir = props.location.search
    ? props.location.search.split("=")[1]
    : "/listaProductoAdmin";

  const productoRegister = useSelector((state) => state.productoRegister);
  const {
    loading: loadingRegister,
    error: errorRegister,
    success: successRegister,
  } = productoRegister;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      ingresaProducto(
        nombre,
        Ensalada,
        Principio,
        Bebida,
      )
    );
    Redirect("/listaProductoAdmin");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (successRegister) {
      props.history.push(redirigir);
    }
  }, [dispatch, props.history, redirigir, successRegister]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="espacio"></div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <div className="card mb-4 orangeclaro">
            <div className="card-header">
              <h3 className="text-center">Crear Almuerzo</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              {loadingRegister && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {successRegister && (
                <MessageBox variant="primary">
                  <h6> PRODUCTO INGRESADO CORRECTAMENTE</h6>
                </MessageBox>
              )}
              {errorRegister && (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">
                  <h6> ERROR AL INGRESAR PRODUCTO</h6>                  <p>{errorRegister}</p>
                </MessageBox>
              )}
              <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>                
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="nombre">
                    Nombre del Producto
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="nombre"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Ingrese Nombre"
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>                

                <div className="form-group ml-2">
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="imagen">
                    Incluye
                  </label>
                  <div className="row border m-2">
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="flexCheckDefault"
                        defaultChecked = {true}
                        value={Ensalada ? false : true}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          habilitaEnsalada(e.target.checked)
                        }
                      />
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        Ensalada
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="flexCheckDefault"
                        defaultChecked = {true}
                        value={Principio ? false : true}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          habilitaPrincipio(e.target.checked)
                        }
                      />
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        Principio
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="flexCheckDefault"
                        defaultChecked = {true}
                        value={Bebida ? false : true}
                        onChange={(e) => habilitaBebida(e.target.checked)}
                      />
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        Bebida
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">
                  Crear Producto
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

¿Cómo hago para que no haya necesidad de volverlos a seleccionar y los guarde?, muchas Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se me ocurre que los dejes *no seleccionados* y al momento de cargar el contenido del DOM, ejecutes la acción `click` sobre cada `checkbox` que necesites seleccionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero al igual sería necesario marcarlo y desmarcarlo para que no vote el error. De uno u otro modo hay que hacerle click